# Write to a socket file descriptor in a test and read them with recv()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, recv

My code loops and calls `recv()`, aggregating TCP bytes to create application messages.

Because the logic is fiddly I'd like to replicate this in a unit test. I don't want to mock (and divert the function call elsewhere). I'd like to `write()` to a file descriptor and execute my code calling `recv()`.

In the test I created a socket and `write()` bytes to the descriptor:

```
MY_TEST()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    write(sock, testData, sizeof(testData));
    char* packets = getPackets(sock);
}
```

However, the above code crashes on `write()` with:

`received signal sigpipe broken pipe`

I presume this is because I haven't called `connect()`.

Is there a simple way to write bytes to a file descriptor in a test and receive them with `recv()`?

Comment: One option is to use unix domain sockets `AF_UNIX`. Of course the receiver has to use that socket type as well when in test mode.

Comment: @kaylum At the moment the non-test code calls `int sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);` to create the socket. Could you elaborate a little further on your suggestion?

Comment: Also, you may need to explain your constraints in more detail. For example, why can't you make a real TCP socket but bind to some loopback and/or test port?

Comment: You can use `socketpair()` to easily make an anonymous pair of unix domain sockets to use for testing.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand some fundamental concepts about TCP - a socket has to be connected to another end before you can use it. I suggest reading through Beej's Guide, or W. Richard Stevens' book Unix Network Programming.